# How to export all Hive databases and their tables to a csv or txt fiile

Tags: python-3.x, shell, unix, hive

I am trying to output all tables in a database to an csv or text file.

I can output all the databases by using "show databases" and I can show all the tables in the databases by using "dal_std" but how to loop through all the tables and export it to a csv or text file is what I am trying to do.

I am new to shell scripts but here is what i have so far:

```
hive -e "show databases" > d.txt

for line in d.txt:
hive -e "show tables in database > output.txt
```

Any ideas or simply ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost reached to an end. just adding up few more details to finish it up!

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Executing the shell script"
hive -e "show databases" > databases.txt
for i in `cat databases.txt`
do
    printf "Given database name has below set of tables:"$i >> tableslist.txt
    printf '\n' >> tableslist.txt
    hive -e "show tables in $i" >> tableslist.txt

done
echo "shell scripts ends"
```

Comment: `for i in $(hive -S -e "show databases")`  is better than storing result in the file and reading it again

Comment: @ leftjoin. Yeah. That would be much better. Thanks